# How to import text file into Array in Python (Pyramid)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text-files, pyramid

Hi so I'm trying to do something pretty simple

I have an `Array` with a ton of sentences being used randomly for a slideDown notification div. Since I don't want to have a really long 1 line in PyCharm I figured I could just import the sentences from a txt file into my `Array`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910322/retrieving-data-from-a-txt-file-using-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-text-file-into-a-list-or-array-with-python/14685073#14685073) so I imported **[numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)**, and using the code below, however, *it breaks*(and skips to my error messages) on the `success_msgs` line, I don't get an error too.

```
def create_request(self):
    # text_file = open("success_requests.txt", "r")
    # lines = text_file.readlines()
    # print lines

    success_msgs = loadtxt("success_request.txt", comments="#", delimiter="_", unpack=False)
    #success_msgs = ['The intro request was sent successfully', "Request sent off, let's see what happens!", "Request Sent. Good luck, may the force be with you.", "Request sent, that was great! Like Bacon."]
```

Any thoughts? :(

My Text File (which is in the same folder as the py file:

```
The intro request was sent successfully_
Request sent off, let's see what happens!_
Request Sent. Good luck, may the force be with you._
Request sent, that was great! Like Bacon._
```

[image]

Debugger
[image]

**my def genfromtxt**

```
def genfromtxt(fname, dtype=float, comments='#', delimiter=None,
           skiprows=0, skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, converters=None,
           missing='', missing_values=None, filling_values=None,
           usecols=None, names=None,
           excludelist=None, deletechars=None, replace_space='_',
           autostrip=False, case_sensitive=True, defaultfmt="f%i",
           unpack=None, usemask=False, loose=True, invalid_raise=True):
```

genfromtxt debug:

[image]

Comment: Using Numpy for this task **does not make any sense**. Fundamentally Numpy is intended for manipulating *numerical* data, and `loadtxt` is intended for loading *two-dimensional* array data from a file, such as represented by a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, tell it to use a string dtype with `dtype='S72'` (or whatever maximum number of characters you expect).

```
In [368]: np.genfromtxt("success_request.txt", delimiter='\n', dtype='S72')
Out[368]: 
array(['The intro request was sent successfully_',
       "Request sent off, let's see what happens!_",
       'Request Sent. Good luck, may the force be with you._',
       'Request sent, that was great! Like Bacon._'], 
      dtype='|S72')
```

Or, if every line ends with an underscore, and you do not want to include the underscores, you could set `delimiter='_'` and `usecols=0` to get only the first column:

```
In [372]: np.genfromtxt("success_request.txt", delimiter='_', usecols=0, dtype='S72')
Out[372]: 
array(['The intro request was sent successfully',
       "Request sent off, let's see what happens!",
       'Request Sent. Good luck, may the force be with you.',
       'Request sent, that was great! Like Bacon.'], 
      dtype='|S72')
```

But there's no reason why you can't just load the file without using numpy with

```
In [369]: s = open("success_request.txt",'r')

In [379]: [line.strip().strip('_') for line in s.readlines()]
Out[379]: 
['The intro request was sent successfully',
 "Request sent off, let's see what happens!",
 'Request Sent. Good luck, may the force be with you.',
 'Request sent, that was great! Like Bacon.']
```

Comment: I'm trying these, but still not working :( 
`s = [np.genfromtxt("success_request.txt", delimiter='\n', dtype='S100')]
    success_msgs = [s]` Having trouble with the open method too.

Comment: @Leon You don't need either of those square brackets.  just `success_msgs = np.genfromtxt("success_request.txt", delimiter='_', usecols=0, dtype='S72')` should be sufficient.  `genfromtxt` returns an array, so you don't need to make a list out of it with brackets.

Comment: @SaulloCastro That also works for me, I end up with `dtype='S51'`.

Comment: Hmm I'm still trying, thanks for your patience, does the added `genformtxt` def and the output help? I tried `dtype=None` also. I'm starting to think perhaps it's something else in this project. Another dev suggested I use a string like `message = """ blah, blah """`

Comment: @Leon I don't understand why you have a `def genfromtxt` line... you should just import it from numpy: `from numpy import genfromtxt`